# How to send multiple string parameters in android volley JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to send the request to the server using Volley library. I saw many tutorial. In them they are using Post method , which I also want to use. But they are sending parameters in the following format :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, String.valueOf(new JSONArray(listMap)),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        Log.d("ASAD", jsonObject.toString());
                        Log.v("ASAD2",listMap.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.d("ASAD", volleyError.toString());
            }
        }
```

so I am getting the error code 1 which is parameters missing 
my service want to get two parameters in string. i.e fb_id and fb token .
where as the procedure which I am using is sending jason arry.

Am I guessing it right, If so then what is the solution ? 
Please help me......

Comment: I think volley is just used to get the data

Answer (score 0):

Following will be one of the many methods to fulfill your requirement:

```
JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
    try
    {

        jsonRequest.put("FullName","Gandalf The Grey");
        jsonRequest.put("LoginPassword","YouShallNotPass");

    } catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonRequest, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```